# Do I need keyboard.close(); to make the code work?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.scanner;

public class assign {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int YEAR;
        int age, bornIn;
        System.out.print("How old are you this year? ");
        age =  keyboard.nextDouble();
        bornIn = YEAR - age;
        System.out.println("I think you were born in " + BornIn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried to run this code?

Comment: Using `scanner.close()` is always good practice to prevent any memory leaks.

Comment: Does adding it make the code work?

Comment: @Victor Polo De Gyves Montero I've tried running it but it has been unsuccessful and need help to make it work.

Comment: @ tgdavies No it changed nothing

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it) / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

The `Scanner` itself is not a resource to be closed. If you pass `System.in`, then you do not need to close it, if you pass some `InputStream` associated with a file, network resource, etc., then you need to close it. Correspondingly, it will not work to reopen the closed `Scanner`, because the stream is closed directly.

Comment: Can you Identify and correct the errors in the program which prompts for the user’s age
and then attempts to work out the year in which the user was born.

Comment: to solve this problem, you need to determine the current date `LocalDate.now()`, and then get the current year